# Can I use different versions of rails in the same machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently analyzing two rails project one of them is in version 2.3.5 and the other one is in version 2.3.4. How can I run both the projects in the same machine?

Comment: Actually I did install both the versions. Mu gem list shows both of them. But when I try to migrate the db for 2.3.4 rails project I get this error

rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `version_requirements' for #<Rails::GemDependency:0x2aa0d88>
D:/ChromeDownloads/echowave/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:in `requirement'

Comment: what if you execute `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Ruby Version Manager (RVM), http://beginrescueend.com/.

It lets you install multiple ruby environments in your home directory. You can also create multiple 'gemsets' specific to each of your 'rubies'.

Now all of your gems, Rails especially, can exist in their own safe environments. You simply switch between each of them. Very very very awesome.

*EDIT*

It appears in your comment to your question that you're using windows...so looks like RVM won't work. The RVM site recommends PIK: http://github.com/vertiginous/pik as a windows alternative.

Comment: `D:/ChromeDownloads/echowave/vendor/rails/` seems like Windows path no RVM for windows thought :(

Comment: Well, my first thought is...get OFF of windows!!! But thats not helpful...so check this out https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/

Answer (score 3):

It's just a question of gems. Bundler handles this for you so there should't be any difficulty.

Detail your question if you face a stumbling block.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which version do you want to use in your project in your `config/environment.rb` file:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Or pass it straight:

```
ruby script/console RAILS_GEM_VERSION='2.3.5'
```

So you can run both of them:

```
# on http://localhost:3000
ruby script/console RAILS_GEM_VERSION='2.3.4' -p 3000
# on http://localhost:3001
ruby script/console RAILS_GEM_VERSION='2.3.5' -p 3001
```